# KeyError 'from_id' Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Ошибка воспроизводится каждое срабатывание не только 'message' хендлера, но и других.
Прошу помочь с фиксом библиотеки vbio, тикет на гитхабе уже создан.

Трейс ошибки:

```
* [2019/May/04 18:16:43] INFO: Pooling started!
* [2019/May/04 18:16:48] ERROR: From message_new
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Evgeny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\vbio\handlers\longpoll.py", line 46, in run
    self.bot.process_message(update['object'])
  File "C:\Users\Evgeny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\vbio\bot.py", line 68, in process_message
    if msg.from_id in self.message_register_next_step:
  File "C:\Users\Evgeny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\vbio\types.py", line 160, in __getattr__
    return self.data[item]
KeyError: 'from_id'
```

Исходный код:

```
import vk_requests
from vbio import VkBot, LongPollClient

api = vk_requests.create_api(service_token='#')  # Токен ВКонтакте
bot = VkBot(api=api)
handler = LongPollClient(bot)


@bot.message_handler()
def hello_world(m):
    m.answer(message='Привет мир!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Решение

Версия api должна быть 5.92.

Comment: Нажмите на кнопку "править" под Вашим вопросом и внесите данную информацию непосредственно в тело вопроса